# Why is a .ISO called a .ISO?

Tags: iso-image

A .ISO is a digital copy of a cd or dvd. Almost 90% of all digital copys end on ".ISO". Why is this? Was there someone that called it .ISO and everyone just copied it?

Comment: Note that there are thousands of ISO standards, in diverse categories.  You'll often here, eg, of "ISO-9000", a standard for running a business.  There are standards for paper, for paint, for railway engineering, etc.

Comment: Soon there will be an ISO standard for how to ask and answer questions about the ISO standards.  Better get ready! ;-)

Comment: And the three letter extension (.ISO) was used due to that being the standard for DOS/Windows systems many of which could not handle longer filenames or extensions.

Comment: Great question, considering how large the ISO standards body is, and how many standards they have, why did a CD format get named after it?

Comment: Just as a trivia, `iso` is also Greek for "same" (or so I've heard)

Comment: Wanted to point out that some programs used different extensions such as CDR or IMG. But ISO seemed to become the standard eventually.

Comment: @ZanLynx note that some CD images are *not* uncompressed bitwise-copies of an ISO-9660  or ISO-13346 file system; those *should not* use an .ISO extension. In your examples, CDR is just the MacOS name for ISO, but IMG could literally be anything (including a floppy disk image).

Comment: what a question! :)

Comment: This has really been bugging me: It's not a .ISO it's **an** .ISO! Right?

Comment: It's "an ISO", but "a dot-ISO". Whether the phrase begins with a vowel depends entirely on whether you pronounce the dot at the beginning. :p

Answer (score 61, accepted):

From the [ISO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_image) [9660](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_9660) standard.

But it's just a way to know what a file is about.

Comment: Thanks its all clear now! It was me failing for not searching it up on Wikipedia.

Comment: The people that coined this term must admit that it does not contain much information. ".966" would have been much more meaningful.

Answer (score 86):

The origin is the [ISO 9660 file system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_9660) which is used on CD-ROM. The extension .iso remained also for DVDs and Blu-Rays which use the [UDF (ISO/IEC 13346)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Disk_Format) file system. See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_image) for details.

Comment: +1 for mentioning that it does not necessarily contain an image with the ISO 9660 file system.

Answer (score 29):

The name is derivated from a norm issued by the *International Organization for Standardization* which specifies the file system on an optical medium [1]. That norm has the abbreviation **ISO 9660** [2] and you can guess now why a CD-ROM image (and later on a DVD-ROM image) usually is named `.iso`.

[1] http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_9660

[2] Some confusion can arise why ISO isn't an acronym of *International Organization for Standardization*. Quoting once again
  [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Organization_for_Standardization#Name_and_abbreviation):

> Recognizing that its initials would be different in different languages, the organization adopted ISO, based on the Greek word isos (ἴσος, meaning equal), as the universal short form of its name.

Comment: So why isn't the filetype `.iofs` or `.ios`?

Comment: @Izkata because the short name of the organization is ISO http://www.iso.org/iso/about/about#2012_aboutiso_iso_name-text-Anchor

Comment: `.iofs` is ruled out at once due to DOS's `8.3` convention (also pointed out by @aldric), for the latterhave a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Organization_for_Standardization why ISO isn't abbreviated as IOS.

Answer (score 7):

The `.iso` extension is an alternate or a shortened form of `.iso9660` or `.isoimg`, which could stand for "ISO 9660-compliant disk image."

The original ISO 9660 standard appears to have been produced in 1988, when PCs were still using 8.3-character filenames (e.g. names could be only 8 characters long, and extensions only 3), so ISO was likely the first choice for shortening the extension to three characters.

Source: [Wikipedia (.isoimg)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_image) and [Wikipedia (.iso9660)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_9660)

Comment: I've never seen a file with a `.isoimg` extension, even on systems that support arbitrarily long extensions, the Wikipedia article you link to doesn't mention it, and a Google search doesn't show anything. Do you have a basis for `.iso` being short for `.isoimg`, as opposed to, say, the phrase "ISO image"?

Comment: He probably meant [this wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_image).